# Auto Refresh Crystal Report and Send to TV screen

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am running Crystal Reports 2008. I want to be able to automatically refresh a report every 10 minutes and send the updated output to a television screen in a hallway to keep employees updated. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you done any research? Stackoverflow is not a free code service.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the File menu and make sure that "Save Data With Report" is turned off